# Camel: stop the route when the jdbc connection loss is detected

Tags: java, tcp, error-handling, routes, apache-camel

I have an application with the following route:

```java
from("netty:tcp://localhost:5150?sync=false&keepAlive=true")
.routeId("tcp.input")
.transform()
.simple("insert into tamponems (AVIS) values (\"${in.body}\");")
.to("jdbc:mydb");
```

This route receives a new message every 59 millisecondes. I want to **stop the route** when the connection to the database is lost, **before that a second message arrives**. And mainly, I want to **never lose a message**.

I proceeded that way:

I added an `errorHandler`:

```java
errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("direct:backup")
.redeliveryDelay(5L)
.maximumRedeliveries(1)
.retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
.logExhausted(false));
```

My `errorHandler` tries to redeliver the message and if it fails again, it redirects the message to a `deadLetterChannel`.

The following deadLetterChannel will stop the `tcp.input` route and try to redeliver the message to the database:

```java
RoutePolicy policy = new StopRoutePolicy();
from("direct:backup")
.routePolicy(policy)
.errorHandler(
  defaultErrorHandler()
  .redeliveryDelay(1000L)
  .maximumRedeliveries(-1)
  .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.ERROR)
)
.to("jdbc:mydb");
```

Here is the code of the `routePolicy`:

```java
public class StopRoutePolicy extends RoutePolicySupport {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(String.class);

  @Override
  public void onExchangeDone(Route route, Exchange exchange) {
    String stop = "tcp.input";
    CamelContext context = exchange.getContext();
    if (context.getRouteStatus(stop) != null && context.getRouteStatus(stop).isStarted()) {
      try {
        exchange.getContext().getInflightRepository().remove(exchange);
        LOG.info("STOP ROUTE: {}", stop);
        context.stopRoute(stop);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        getExceptionHandler().handleException(e);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

My problems with this method are:

- In my `"direct:backup"` route, if I set the `maximumRedeliveries` to -1 the route `tcp.input` will never stop
- I'm loosing messages during the stop
- This method for detecting the connection loss and for stopping the route is too long

Please, does anybody have an idea for **make this faster** or for make this differently in order to **not lose message**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found a way to resolve my problems. In order to make the application faster, I added **asynchronous processes** and **multithreading** with seda.

```
from("netty:tcp://localhost:5150?sync=false&keepAlive=true").to("seda:break");


from("seda:break").threads(5)
.routeId("tcp.input")
.transform()
.simple("insert into tamponems (AVIS) values (\"${in.body}\");")
.to("jdbc:mydb");
```

I did the same with the backup route.

```
from("seda:backup")
.routePolicy(policy)
.errorHandler(
  defaultErrorHandler()
  .redeliveryDelay(1000L)
  .maximumRedeliveries(-1)
  .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.ERROR)
).threads(2).to("jdbc:mydb");
```

And I modified the routePolicy like that:

```
public class StopRoutePolicy extends RoutePolicySupport {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(String.class);

  @Override
  public void onExchangeBegin(Route route, Exchange exchange) {
    String stop = "tcp.input";
    CamelContext context = exchange.getContext();
    if (context.getRouteStatus(stop) != null && context.getRouteStatus(stop).isStarted()) {
      try {
        exchange.getContext().getInflightRepository().remove(exchange);
        LOG.info("STOP ROUTE: {}", stop);
        context.stopRoute(stop);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        getExceptionHandler().handleException(e);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onExchangeDone(Route route, Exchange exchange) {
    String stop = "tcp.input";
    CamelContext context = exchange.getContext();
    if (context.getRouteStatus(stop) != null && context.getRouteStatus(stop).isStopped()) {
      try {
        LOG.info("RESTART ROUTE: {}", stop);
        context.startRoute(stop);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        getExceptionHandler().handleException(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With these updates, the TCP route is stopped before the backup route is processed. And the **route is restarted when the jdbc connection is back**.

Now, thanks to Camel, **the application is able to handle a database failure** without losing message and without manual intervention.

I hope this could help you.